# If $A_{ij}$ is rank $2$ tensor, show that $\frac{\partial(A_{ij})}{\partial x_k}$ is a rank $3$ tensor.

Tags: derivatives, tensors, tensor-rank

> If $A_{ij}$ is grade $2$ tensor, show that :
>
> $$\frac{\partial(A_{ij})}{\partial x_k}$$
>
> is a grade 3 tensor.

Solution :

$$\frac{\partial(A_{ij})}{\partial x_k}= \frac{\partial(A_{ij})}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial(A_{ij})}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial(A_{ij})}{\partial x_3} = A_{ij,k}$$

which has $3$ free pointers, hence it's a grade $3$ tensor.

Is my approach correct and as thorough as it could be ?

Comment: This terminology is a bit nonstandard. What is your definition for the "grade" of a tensor?

Comment: @Spencer I mean rank, eventually the number of quantities it represents, like if it's a grade/rank 2 tensor -> 9 quantities, if it's rank 3 -> 27 quantities

Comment: Rank usually would have to do with the transformation properties. Not just the number of quantities it represents.

Comment: @Spencer No problem ! I'm Greek so I don't know every bit of terminology, working on it ! So, is the solution correct ? Is it missing something to make it 100% thorough ?

Comment: There's no summation on $k$ !!

Comment: @TedShifrin What do you mean by that ? Sorry, I'm a bit of a total rookie on tensors so I'm just trying to grasp stuff !

Comment: You shouldn't have added those three terms together.

Comment: @Spencer Can you provide me with a thorough solution or explanation ? I'm having a hard time understanding my mistake

Comment: $k$ is fixed, just as $i$ and $j$ are. You only sum, according to the Einstein summation convention, when the same index appears both up and down.  (That's called contraction, like trace of a matrix.)

Comment: @TedShifrin So what should I do here to prove what I'm asked for ?

Comment: You have transformation rules you have been told to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all has to do with transformation properties. When there is a change in coordinates the tensors are supposed to change in a very particular way.

Suppose there is a change from coordinates $x^j$ to coordinates $(x')^{j}$.

Then a rank 0 tensor field will be a scalar which doesn't change.

$$ \phi' =\phi $$

A rank 1 tensor field transforms in the following way,

$$ (A')^{\mu} = \frac{\partial (x')^{\mu}}{\partial x^\alpha} A^\alpha$$

A rank two tensor field transforms like the product of two rank 1 fields,

$$ (A')^\mu (B')^\nu = \frac{\partial (x')^{\nu}}{\partial x^\beta}\frac{\partial (x')^{\mu}}{\partial x^\alpha} A^\alpha B^\beta$$

$$ (T')^{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial (x')^{\nu}}{\partial x^\beta}\frac{\partial (x')^{\mu}}{\partial x^\alpha} T^{\alpha\beta}$$

These are the rules for contravariant indices (the raised ones). For covariant indices (sub-scripted indices)the rank 1 tensor transforms slightly differently.

$$ (A')_{\mu} = \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial (x')^{\mu}} A_\alpha$$

You must show that your object transforms as a rank three covariant tensor.